# Android Studio is giving me a weird error when I attempt to create a drawable resource file

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? I tried using chown on the directory, and that still didn't work.

Error reads: "Cannot modify a read-only directory '/opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar!/android/graphics'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `background` file in `res` and it seems odd that `ic_launcher.png` is showing up as a directory.

Comment: I'm trying to create the file background when I do this, but it gives me this error.